# My list is being over sliced when writing to CSV

Tags: python, loops, csv, iteration

I am trying to write to a CSV, but when I attempt to iterate while writing to a CSV (either using a for loop or via the writerows), my output not only slices my list, but also slices the strings within the list. Please help!

[image]
[image]
[image]

code:

import csv

```
FileName= input("Enter the name of your master file here: ")
if len(FileName)<1: FileName="MasterCustomerList.csv"
FileOpen=open(FileName)
lst=list()
count=0
for lines in FileOpen:
    count=count+1
    lines=lines.rstrip()
    pieces=lines.split(',')
    if pieces[7]=="Yes":
        lst.append(pieces[2]+" "+pieces[1]+" "+pieces[0])
lst.sort()
for items in lst:
     print(items)


with open("CC_Customers.csv", "w", newline="") as DataFile:
    DataFileWriter = csv.writer(DataFile)
    DataFileWriter.writerows(lst)
DataFile.close()
```

Comment: Please do copy the code into Stack Overflow if possible, it is easier to reproduce the probelm.

Comment: Sorry, just added the code

Comment: Can you also add the interactive python output for `>>> lst` or `>>> lst[:5]` instead of printing it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [ask] and the [mcve] guidelines. Images of text prevent answers from cut-n-pasting code for testing. Also providing a few lines of sample input and expected output (also as text!) helps us test and build an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

`csv.writerows` requires a list of lists, not a list of strings.  Since strings are iterable,  you were getting a single character as they are being iterated.

Since the output isn't really a CSV, you should use the CSV module to read the file, and not write the file.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that strings are in most respects treated as lists of characters in Python. A CSV file contains N rows and M columns, thus the input to `writerows()` is a list of list where the outer list are the N rows, and the inner list has M elements of that row (one for each column). A dirty quickfix would be to `DataFileWriter.writerows([[elm] for elm in lst])`, but to be honest I'd rather just write each line as a normal file.

Here is your code cleaned up, and with just directly writing each line:

```
import csv

file_name = input("Enter the name of your master file here: ")
if len(file_name) == 0:
    file_name = "MasterCustomerList.csv"

output = list()

with open(file_name) as file:
    for count, lines in enumerate(file):
        pieces = lines.rstrip().split(',')
        if pieces[7] == "Yes":
            output.append(pieces[2] + " " + pieces[1] + " " + pieces[0])

output.sort()

for items in output:
    print(items)

with open("CC_Customers.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    file.writelines(output)
```

(Not sure about the `newline=""`, but kept it)